# when to use WindowPopup or Dialog or Fragment Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

I have read in the documentation and this is what i have learned

**Dialog**

> Base class for Dialogs.
>
> Note: Activities provide a facility to manage the creation, saving and
>   restoring of dialogs. See onCreateDialog(int), onPrepareDialog(int,
>   Dialog), showDialog(int), and dismissDialog(int). If these methods are
>   used, getOwnerActivity() will return the Activity that managed this
>   dialog.

Thus **FragmentDialog** is just a subclass of Dialog which is in a fragment and thus disconnected from the creating Activity life cycle

> A fragment that displays a dialog window, floating on top of its
>   activity's window. This fragment contains a Dialog object, which it
>   displays as appropriate based on the fragment's state. Control of the
>   dialog (deciding when to show, hide, dismiss it) should be done
>   through the API here, not with direct calls on the dialog.

and **WindowPopup** is disconnected from creating Activity's life cycle (so what is it differ from FragmentDialog?)

*Is WindowPopup more like a toast message going on top of all activities even when app is invisible?

*when should i use each of them?

*other differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710361/when-to-use-android-popupwindow-vs-dialog

Comment: i think [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165454/should-i-use-a-popupwindow-or-dialogfragment-for-accepting-input) will help you.